# Invalid key bindings after upgrade to ubuntu 18.04 from 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I need a shortcut `Alt + 1` in Intellij IDEA but after Ubuntu upgrade it results into `Alt + plus`. However other numbers like `Alt + 2` behave as expected. And hitting `1` indeed results into writing `1` in text editors. Only the shortcuts turn `1` into `+` for some reason.

It happens with any keys like `alt`, `shift`, `ctrl` together with `1` ... I tried more keyboard layouts but it happens in each of them.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this is obviously a buggy behavior but I managed to solve it by having US keyboard layout at the top position in Keyboard setting. As the second Czech layout that I have has `+` where US layout has `1`. When I have Czech layout as the primary one, even though US layout is currently active. This bug happens.